# Facebook api work only for me

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm creating frame app for facebook. 
Following code work good for me:

```
function changeToHome() {
  try {
    var time = new Date();
    FB.api("/me", {fields: "id,first_name,last_name,picture"}, function(response)
    {
        window.location = '#home';
        var fname = encodeURIComponent(response.first_name);
        var lname = encodeURIComponent(response.last_name);
        var avatar = encodeURIComponent(response.picture.data.url);
        var u = '?useradd='+response.id+"&fn="+fname+"&ln="+lname+"&p="+avatar+"&t="+time.getTime();
        document.getElementById('game_frame').src=('drop.html'+u);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'stat-api.php'+u
        }).done(function() {
            //alert("done");
        });
    });
    } catch(ex) {
      //alert(ex);
    }
}
```

But if i try to test it trought other acounts the facebook api doesn't work( I tried different browsers and got the same result.

Comment: is your app published? While your app is under development you need to add people to the group of testers. You can do this from https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: Yes. I have two tester. They both can't normal use app. For them "response" is undefined:(

Comment: You should post your solution as a response so it fits in better with the rest of the solved questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable (or disable) sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It didn't authenticate my app! It was a reason.

Include folowing in window.fbAsyncInit = function() {...}

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
    //var uid = response.authResponse.userID; //FACEBOOK_ID
    //var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;/ //ACCESS TOKEN
    if (response.authResponse) {
        // logged in and connected user, someone you know. 
        //  YOUR CODE HERE
            changeToHome()
    }
    }else {
      attemptLogin();
    }
    });

function attemptLogin(){
   FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
              //  YOUR CODE HERE
              changeToHome()
        } else {
          //if user didn't logged in or didn't authorize your application
      }
  }, {scope: 'offline_access,publish_stream,manage_pages,publish_actions,user_games_activity'}); //YOUR PERMISSION
}
```